# Is there formula specifically for identifying duplicate websites in a column or row?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

I have a long list of websites and need some way of identifying if there are any duplicate sites.

For instance:

- https://www.forbes.com/leadership/#3364f19f1d66
- www.inc.com
- forbes.com/sites/constancedierickx/2020/01/31/wework-and-the-charisma-proxy/#4175162f52c7
- https://www.inc.com/emily-canal/120-water-audit-clean-water-best-industries-2020.html?icid=hmsub1

Is there some sort of add on or formula for google sheets to detect that this list as having duplicates? (there are 2 INC pages so that's a pair of duplicates and 2 Forbes pages which is another pair of duplicates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(IFERROR(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A:A, "https?://www.|https?://|www.", ), "/"),,1), 
 "\.(.+\..+)"), INDEX(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A:A, "https?://www.|https?://|www.", ), "/"),,1))), 
 IFERROR(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A:A, "https?://www.|https?://|www.", ), "/"),,1), 
 "\.(.+\..+)"), INDEX(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A:A, "https?://www.|https?://|www.", ), "/"),,1))))>1, 
 "Duplicate", ))
```

[image: 0]